# Can I have an anonymous function that isn't typed as a closure in Rust?

Tags: function, lambda, closures, rust, anonymous-function

I'm using 1.6.0 (stable), but any future/nightly feature that enables this or that I can watch/track is cool too.

what I'd like in theory (simplified for brevity):

```
let a:fn(&lib_plotMote::mask::Mask) -> bool = {fn(_)->true};
```

the closest I've gotten:

```
let a:fn(&lib_plotMote::mask::Mask) -> bool = { fn anon(_:&Mask)->bool{true}; anon };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Closures *are* the "anonymous function" feature of Rust.

That said, you can *slightly* reduce the redundancy in what you have:

```rust
let a: fn(_) -> _ = { fn anon(_: &Mask) -> bool { true }; anon };
```

Comment: That's too bad, because a function that doesn't close over anything has a named type and can be used in a collection, whereas a closure cannot for obvious reasons.

Comment: @CamdenNarzt are you trying to create a collection of functions with different types? Maybe if you expanded a bit on your scenario there might be an alternative

Comment: Well I'm trying to decide what to do with a collection of functions with different types in another unrelated section of code, but in this case I'm trying to hoist a branch out of a loop.

Comment: > Closures -are_ the "anonymous function" feature of Rust.

Don't forget about function pointers, of which this is.  These aren't closures, they're function poointers.